# How to get System.Data.SQLite Database File Option in DataSource

Tags: sqlite, edmx

I've followed below tutorials
http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2013/12/22/portable-databases-ii-using-sqlite-with-entity-framework.aspx

But after installation of System.Data.SQLite using Net-Gu Package manager, no option is available for **SQLite Database File** in
 [image: Change Data Source]

Answer (score 1):

I found myself in the same problem. What it works for me is follow the explanation in this ticket: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview/2be4298631c01be99475

But basically, after deleting the following lines in the App.config it worked:

```
<add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
```

`<remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SQLite pre required dll for window from following link:
http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

[image]

Comment: Above works only on x86 Architecture or 32-bit machines. But I've 64-bit machine.

Comment: @PrakashVishwakarma Try in Visual Studio 10

Answer (score 0):

Download this file if you use VS 2013:

https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.94.0/sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.94.0.exe

For complete list: https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki