# How to bind a DataGridView to a SQLite Database?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, datagridview

I'm trying to add a data connection to a datagridview that uses SQLite. I've added the reference to SQLite (downloaded the required files) but when I go through the wizard to add a data source, SQLite is not included in the choices -
 see screenshot below:

[image: Change Data Source]

I've looked around for answers to this question but have not been successful in finding any.

Here is a screenshot of the database inside my project folder:

[image: project folder]

Is there any way to bind the datagridview to a sqlite data source?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The steps below are copied from http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2013/12/22/portable-databases-ii-using-sqlite-with-entity-framework.aspx:

1. Go to Tools > Library Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for solution...
2. Choose the Online section and write SQLite inside the textbox located on the upper-right corner. Push ENTER and wait for the search to be performed.
3. Choose the first package: System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64).
4. Once the package has been downloaded, select the project in which to install the provider and press OK.

*If the data source still isn't available after following the above steps don't work, it may be a problem with the SQLite version - see [the comment left by cmc](http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2013/12/22/portable-databases-ii-using-sqlite-with-entity-framework.aspx#642454) and the [linked thread](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/sqlite-data-source-not-available-td78521.html), which says version 1.0.93 works but version 1.0.94 doesn't.*

Comment: unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work. I'm using version 1.0.105.2 (the latest under nuget)

Comment: no, I don't see it listed under NuGET, just 1.0.105.2

Comment: The older version needs to be downloaded manually - see the [bottom post in the thread](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/sqlite-data-source-not-available-td78521.html#d1420821460917-378) and its links to [32 bit](http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.93.0/sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.93.0.exe) and [64 bit](http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.93.0/sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x64-2010-1.0.93.0.exe) versions of 1.0.93.

Comment: downloaded that and installed and added the reference but these steps (http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2013/12/22/portable-databases-ii-using-sqlite-with-entity-framework.aspx) are not working, as I don't see the sqlite option for the entity model

Comment: Well it seems like the whole thing with SQLite and Visual Studio is a bit of a mess - the current answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089346) don't exactly inspire confidence but might possibly get you there if you're prepared to be fix to particular versions and put in some effort. In particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089346#32228932) is the nearest to what's described above.

Comment: really frustrating, oh well

Comment: yeah i was following the instructions in that video but i have no idea what is going on. I have Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition so maybe that's it because everything that was done on the video I did and it still will not work.

Comment: Another very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285676/how-to-get-system-data-sqlite-database-file-option-in-datasource

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Tools > Library Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for solution...
2. Choose the Browse section and search for Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact
3. Install it
4. Click on View > Other Windows > SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox will be 
   appeared there.
5. Click on SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox and you can easily manage 
   connection. Screenshots are attached

   [image]

   [image].

Comment: unfortunately it does not appear (view->other windows->sqlite/sql).

Comment: The SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox window comes from this Visual Studio extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox , probably not from the NuGet packages

Answer (score 0):

`System.Data.SQLite`'s website now says that its "design-time components" (which I believe power this "Data Source" feature in the Visual Studio UI) are now no longer "officially supported", and don't work in Visual Studio 2017 and later anyway "due to changes in the Visual Studio package installation model": https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki .

There is a separate 3rd-party ["SQLite and SQL Server Compact Toolbox" Visual Studio Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox) which provides a database explorer UI window and an SQLite Data Source, but I was unable to get the latter to work myself (in VS2019).

In the end I just did the binding myself somewhat manually in code. The `SQLite*` classes in `System.Data.SQLite` snap in to the same kinds of `.DataSource` stuff shown in this standard Winforms DataGridView binding tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

```cs
using System.Data.SQLite;

var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + pathToDbFile);
var dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(
    "SELECT * from [Table1]",
    dbConn
);

// These can be constructed manually or created in the Designer
DataGridView dataGridView1;
BindingSource bindingSource1;

// This binding can be done manually in constructor/on Load event, or also done via properties in the Designer
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

// Now, on form load or other event, the .Fill method of SQLiteDataAdapter
// can be used just like the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter class
// in the tutorial
{
    // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
    DataTable table = new DataTable
    {
        Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    };
    dataAdapter.Fill(table);
    bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

    // Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content.
    dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(
        DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
}
```