# Create a sqlite table from datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview

I have a datagridview in my C# form App.

How can I create a table directly from datagridview whenever a button is pressed.

Since the datagridview is editable I don't know how many rows of columns there will be to save in the database.

How can I save the whole datagridview to a database and retrieve them?
Can I use a unique id as a table name and then use that??

Comment: This might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798832/how-to-bind-a-datagridview-to-a-sqlite-database

Comment: Bind dgv to DataTable, List or other appropriate collection type. Create a button click handler which writes data from the bound collection to DB.

Comment: i need to create a TABLE every time a a button is pressed..binding helps only if there is already a table right?

Comment: just create a table and then loop foreach DGV row and insert a row inside that table...