# Connecting a DataGridView to SQLite in .NET 5.0 WinForms

Tags: winforms, sqlite, datagridview, .net-5, dataadapter

In a .Net 5.0 WinForms project I have connected a DataGridView to an SQL Server table by the following objects:

```
SQL Server table
SQLDataAdapter
SQLCommandBuilder
DataTable
BindingSource
DataGridView
```

This setting allows reading and writing.

Now I would like to use this DataGridView for **SQLite**, too. But `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` doesn't contain a `DataAdapter` [(link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/compare), and `System.Data.SQLite` [(link)](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q3) seems not to be available for .NET 5.0.

Is this a fact that I have to accept or am I missing anything (hopefully)? Or is there another way to connect a DataGridView to SQLite for reading and writing without me spending months studying the underlying technologies? I'm a beginner, that's why I'm asking.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798832/how-to-bind-a-datagridview-to-a-sqlite-database) but the links refer to quite old stuff.

Thank you for any hints.